# Second order homogenous recurrence with non constant coefficients

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, solution-verification, hypergeometric-function

I'm dealing with a recurrence which I do not know how to tackle and my steps may be wrong. Some suggestions for a solutions are greatly appreciated.

Consider $\alpha,\beta,\gamma \in \mathbb{R^+}$ and the following recurrence:

\begin{equation}
\alpha\beta G(n+1)+n\gamma G(n-1) - n\beta\gamma G(n)=0
\end{equation}

The best way I could think on how to solve is using a $Z$ transform but if my steps are correct it correspends to compute the solution to a non linear diffrential equation in $z$:

\begin{equation}
\alpha\beta zX(z) + \gamma \frac{1}{z}\left(-z\dfrac{X(z)}{dz}\right) + \beta\gamma\left(z\dfrac{X(z)}{dz}\right) = 0
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\dfrac{dX(z)}{dz}(z\beta\gamma-\gamma)+z \alpha\beta X(z)=0
\end{equation}

Is there any other way I can try to obtain a non numerical solution?

Comment: This is still a linear differential equation, the coefficients are just nonconstant. There might be some magic you can do with hypergeometric functions.

Comment: Interesting. Have you ever used this magic?

Comment: Nope! Where does this problem come from?

Comment: I'm working on a problem emerging from chemical master equations (CME). In particular I found that the equation I have highlighted emerges from appying (a function of) the eigenfunctions of the CME to G. Finding G hence allows me to unleash several results downstream.

In all honesty this is also a semplification as the more general case would amount to solving a non homogenous, non constant in parameters and bidimensional recurrence equation. Kind of a counter part of a pde in continous I guess.

Comment: For the double sided Z-Transform, at least, $Z\left\{nx[n-1]\right\} = \dfrac{1}{z}X(z) -\dfrac{d}{dz}X(z)$